# vim stops sending text to * (X11) register?

Tags: vim, x-server

I recently started using VcXsrv with the hope of being able to grab text from `vim` (console mode) to the Windows clipboard via X11 forwarding (and the `*` register). It works...to an extent. As soon as I paste to Notepad, I lose the ability to yank to the Windows clipboard.

- I'm experiencing this issue whether I yank text to the `*` register directly, or use the `autoselect` clipboard option. (`:help options` (clipboard), `:help guioptions_a`)
- It doesn't appear to be tied to a specific Xserver: I've tried VcXsrv, XMing, and MobaXterm (including PuTTY w/ Moba's X Server).
- It doesn't appear to be tied to the terminal I'm using. I've tried PuTTY and MobaXterm.
- `xclip` can be used any number of times outside of `vim` with no issues.
- Echoing a command to `xclip` seems to temporarily fix the problem. I can successfully copy yank to `"*` from `vim` again, but as soon as I paste to the Windows notepad, the problem is back.
- `~/.vim/autoload` and `~/.vim/plugin` are empty.
- I use `tmux` regularly, but experience this problem outside of a session as well.
- Happens with `gvim` as well.

My `.vimrc`:

```
$ cat ~/.vimrc
" Default vimrc file, installed by vim spell
set mouse=a
set nocompatible
set backspace=indent,eol,start
" set autoindent
" set smartindent
set cindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set ruler
set showcmd
colorscheme elflord
syntax enable
if &term =~ "^screen"
  set ttymouse=xterm
endif
filetype plugin on
```

Output of `set clipboard`:

```
clipboard=autoselect,exclude:cons\|linux
```

Output of `vim --version`:

```
$ vim --version | head -20
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Jul 12 2010 02:29:33)
Included patches: 1-445
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by jamessan@debian.org
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
+cryptv +cscope +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs +dnd -ebcdic
+emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path
+float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand
+jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap
+menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm
-mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +multi_byte
+multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra +perl +postscript
+printer +profile +python +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind
+signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax
+tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white +tcl +terminfo +termresponse
+textobjects +title +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual
+visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup
+X11 -xfontset +xim +xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
```

---

Update:

`:echo @*` will show the contents of the `*` register properly even after the bug manifests, so it appears that it's not arriving in the Windows clipboard via my X servers for some reason.

Comment: I'm using VIM over [mRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org/) SSH session. And everything is working like a charm. I'm coping text via Shift+selection.

Comment: @yegorich I know how shift selection works, but it's not what this topic is about. It's not possible to yank the entire contents of a file (including what is off screen) to the clipboard using that method.

Comment: I was able to make this problem go away at home by upgrading to a more recent version of `vim`, but I'm experiencing it again at work with RHEL5 and vim 7.0 (`vim-7.0.109-7.2.el5` RPM package / `vimx` binary). Adding a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

> I know how shift selection works...It's not possible to yank the entire contents of a file (including what is off screen) to the clipboard using that method.

I don't know if it will work via X forwarding into windows, but try the `*` register for that.  Go to the top, in normal (not --INSERT--) mode, `"*10000yy` (yank 10000 lines into register `*`).  **Register `*` is the X clipboard,** so you can paste that anywhere in X; if you have some method of transferring that to the windows clipboard you're set.

`"*` is a hassle because of the shift combo. If you do this a lot, map `"*` to an F key or something:

```
:nmap <F8> "*
:vmap <F8> "*
```

That maps for normal mode and visual mode, so you can ctrl-v select stuff too.

Comment: I deleted the last comment after some further testing. Your suggestion bypasses the clipboard autodetection (`:help guioptions_a`), which is already sending the yanked text to the `*` register. I'm experiencing the same issue when yanking to it directly though.

Comment: Actually, reading that text file further, I'm misunderstanding what's happening. Pressing `y` isn't yanking it to `*`, it's simply the fact that I'm highlighting the text in visual mode. In either event, the `*` register is breaking after the first paste for some reason. I'll update my question with appropriate terminology.